# What is the difference between qr/ and m/ in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, precompiled

From Perldoc:

```
qr/STRING/msixpodualn
```

> This operator quotes (and possibly compiles) its STRING as a regular
> expression. STRING is interpolated **the same way as PATTERN in
> m/PATTERN/**.

```
m/PATTERN/msixpodualngc
/PATTERN/msixpodualngc
```

> Searches a string for a pattern match, and in scalar context returns
> true if it succeeds, false if it fails. If no string is specified via
> the =~ or !~ operator, the $_ string is searched. (The string
> specified with =~ need not be an lvalue--it may be the result of an
> expression evaluation, but remember the =~ binds rather tightly.) See
> also perlre.
>
> **Options are as described in qr// above**

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but it's not clear at all to me how these options are different - they seem basically synonymous. When would you use `qr//` instead of `m//`, or vice versa?

Answer (score 5):

The `m//` operator is for matching, whereas `qr//` produces a pattern (as a string) that you can stick in a variable and store for later. It's a *quoted regular expression* pattern.

Pre-compiling the this way is useful for optimising your run-time cost, e.g. if you are using a fixed pattern in a loop with millions of iterations, or you want to pass patterns around between function calls or use them in a dispatch table.

```perl
# match now
if ( $foo =~ m/pattern/ ) { ... }

# compile and use later
my $pattern = qr/pattern/i;
print $pattern;                      # (?^ui:pattern)

if ($foo =~ m/$pattern/) { ... }
```

The structure of the string (in this example, `(?^ui:pattern)`) is explained [in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3Fadlupimnsx-imnsx)). Basically `(?:)` creates a sub-pattern with built-in flags, and the `^` says which flags not to have. You can use this inside other patterns too, to turn on and off case-insensitivity for parts of your pattern for example.

Comment: In addition to speed, pre-compiled patterns also make the code more readable and maintainable, if the same pattern is reused. They are especially handy if the `pattern` is long and/or complex.